# LWC and Absolute Humidity

Tags: meteorology, humidity

What is the difference between "liquid water content" and "absolute humidity" in meteorology? Both have units of mass/volume.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the online chapter [Water Vapor](http://www.eos.ubc.ca/books/Practical_Meteorology/Chapters/Ch04-Moist.pdf) (University of British Columbia), the two variables you ask about are defined as:

**Absolute humidity**

$$\rho_{v}=\frac{m_{water\ vapour}}{volume}$$

**Liquid water content**

$$\rho_{LWC}=\frac{m_{liquid\ water}}{volume}$$

The main difference is that absolute humidity measures the mass of water *vapour* and the LWC measures the mass of suspended or falling *liquid* water content in a unit volume of air. A handy definition linking the two terms is (from the linked document):

> LWC is the liquid-water analogy to the absolute
>   humidity for water vapor.

Comment: Thank you the answer and the reference - this really cleared it up for me!

Comment: @boxofchalk1 happy to have helped! I was able to learn something new too.